# Best method to validate a multiply imputed Cox model with R?

Tags: r, predictive-models, survival, validation, rms

This question is with regards to using a test data set to validate an imputed Cox model using R.  With a non-imputed data set I would use `val.surv()` from `rms`, but I'm not sure how/if I can use it with my multiply imputed data set.

Further explanation:
I created a predictive Cox PH model for 5-year RFS, and also used the `mice` package to multiply impute some missing data in the training data set.  I then used `fit.mult.impute()` in Dr. Frank Harrell's excellent `Hmisc` package to obtain the pooled model.  I have a data set that I would like to test the model on, but I am not sure how best to validate the pooled model.

Multiple imputation is a common procedure that many researchers utilize, so there must be a way that R users are validating their models with imputed data.  I would like to know what functions/avenues are available for me to test this pooled model with my validation data set?  Here is some sample code to work with:

```
library(rms)
library(survival)
library(mice)

remove(veteran)
data(veteran)
veteran$trt=factor(veteran$trt,levels=c(1,2))
veteran$prior=factor(veteran$prior,levels=c(0,10))

#Set random data to NA 
veteran[sample(137,4),1]=NA
veteran[sample(137,4),2]=NA
veteran[sample(137,4),7]=NA

impvet=mice(veteran)
survmod=with(veteran,Surv(time,status))

#make a CPH for each imputation
for(i in seq(5)){
    assign(paste("mod_",i,sep=""),cph(survmod~celltype+karno,
        data=complete(impvet,i),x=T,y=T))
}

#Now there is a CPH model for mod_1, mod_2, mod_3, mod_4, and mod_5.

pooled_mod=fit.mult.impute(survmod~celltype+karno,cph,impvet,data=veteran,surv=T)

#Here is a test data set.
remove(veteran)
test_dat=data.frame(trt=replicate(500,NA), celltype=replicate(500,NA), time=replicate(500,NA), status=replicate(500,NA), karno=replicate(500,NA), diagtime=replicate(500,NA), age=replicate(500,NA), prior=replicate(500,NA))
for(i in seq(8)){
test_dat[,i]=sample(veteran[,i],500,replace=T)
}

#Now there is a pooled model, "pooled_mod", and a test data set, "test_dat".
```

I'm looking forward to hearing about the R methods that can help in this situation.

Comment: You might be interested in the Amelia package which has some features for assessing imputed data built in. The vignette for the package is pretty comprehensive (pdf): http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Amelia/vignettes/amelia.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that you repeat every step that you would otherwise do on the non-imputed data for the first imputed data set. For example:

```
# fit the model on the multiply imputed data
fit <- with(impvet, cph(survmod ~ celltype + karno, x = T, y = T))

# take out the first imputed data set
data <- complete(fit, 1)

# take out the first fitted cph model
mod <- fit$analyses[[1]]

# use your val.surv() steps here on the first imputed data set
...
```

Of course, you can also study the second, third, … dataset.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  Are you saying that I should validate only the model that is based on one of the imputations?  Surely there is a way that R users are validating their models pooled from multiple imputations?  Or is this a circumstance where SAS trumps R?

Comment: JJM, I understand your confusion. Preferably you should do all m analyses, and pool the results. My interpretation of your question was how to apply val.surv() in the context of multiple imputation. All I'm saying is: Apply it to the m imputed data sets, and not to "the pooled model".